# Find load offset from global offset table

Tags: assembly, arm

I want to find  _DYNAMIC structure offset which reside on  _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_[0] in AArch64 at start-up and GOT entries not relocated yet.

I wrote code in assembly.

```
    .text
    .globl _start
    .type _start,%function

_start:
        mov     x0, sp
        sub     sp, sp, #132

        /* Find our load offset at GOT[0]  */
        ldr     x1, .Lpool
.LPIC0: add     x1, x1, .LPIC0  // x1=address of _DYNAMIC
        ldr     x2, .Lpool+4
        add     x2, x2, .LPIC0  // x2=address of GOT
        ldr     x2, [x2]        // x2=GOT[0]
        sub     x1, x1, x2      // load offset of _DYNAMIC

        bl      my_function

        ldr     x1, [sp]
        mov     sp, x1
        br      x0

        .align  2
.Lpool: .word   _DYNAMIC-.LPIC0
        .word   _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_-.LPIC0

        .size _start,.-_start
```

When I run the code I am getting segmentation fault, (debugging shows) on following line of code:

```
ldr     x2, [x2]
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A comment on each line would help you to get your question answered faster. As it stands, the absence of commenting is a roadblock to those who want to help you.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger on this snippet?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky I have described exact line where I got segmentation fault after debugging.

Comment: When you do `objdump -d` on your binary, do the values in the pool look sane? Do they correspond to the offset to the right symbols? Are the ELF load flags set right on the sections containing the GOT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to write the correct code for loading the offset from got table in AArch64.
Below is the code.

```
    /* Find our load offset at GOT[0]  */
    adrp    x1, _DYNAMIC
    add     x1, x1,#:lo12:_DYNAMIC   \\ address of _DYNAMIC

    adrp    x2, _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
    ldr     x2, [x2,#:lo12:_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_]  \\GOT[0]

    sub     x1, x1, x2
```

Answer (score 1):

AArch64 addresses are 64-bit, and `ldr x` reads 64-bit, but your `.word` are only 32-bit. This leads to the addresses ending up all wrong.

Increase the size of the fields in the pool, and using `+8` to load the second value.

In any case, in order to permit programs larger than 2G you should be using 64-bit offsets.

You might also want to rethink what mode you use to load GOT[0]. `ldr w2, [x2]` might be right, but you'll have to confirm that.